# generically add a listener to a DOM object that will get called anytime the object is updated?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web

In other words is it possible to generically add a listener to a DOM object so anytime that object changes the listener gets called?

I know you can create event listeners for user interaction like click and mouse over (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) but I'm unaware of any sort of update listener or how that would work.

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver